# Idw Spatial Interpolation Method

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/JoranBeaufort/Leaflet.idw) for performing idw interpolation method. But when I use my own data, the error is "idw is not a function"

```
function idw(geojson) {
  debugger;
  coords = []; //define an array to store coordinates

  onEachFeature: function (geojson.feature, geojsonLayer) {
     // popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
     // layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
     coords.push(feature.geometry.coordinates);
   }

  for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
    var lat = coords[i][0];
    var lon = coords[i][1];
    var intensity = coords[i][2];
    var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(lat, lon);
    var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation).bindPopup(popupText).addTo(map);
  }

  var idw = L.idwLayer(coords, {
    opacity: 0.3,
    maxZoom: 18,
    cellSize: 10,
    exp: 3,
    max: 1200
  });

  map.addLayer(idwLayer);
}
```

Comment: You're defining idw twice here. Once as a function and later as a variable. Try renaming the variable.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and to make it work, I just added:

```
<script src="js/leaflet-idw+directdraw.js"></script>
```